# How to import and use luxon in a vuejs project?

Tags: javascript, datetime, vuejs2, luxon

I'm facing this error when I try to use `luxon` in my **vuejs2** project.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined
```

I installed the lib using npm, and imported in my component :

```
import DateTime from 'luxon'
const exmpl = DateTime.local()
```

Can you guys show me what I did wrong or even propose an other librairie for time manipulation that can work easily with vuejs.

Comment: https://moment.github.io/luxon/ suggests `import { DateTime } from 'luxon'`, with braces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because `DateTime` is not correctly imported.

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation on what is the difference between import with braces and without them ?

Comment: I've added a post answer for `importing modules in ES6` below. Please refer to it.

Comment: I think a simpler way to explain this is that Luxon exports an object like `{ DateTime: ..., Interval: ..., Duration: ...}` (see [here](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/src/luxon.js)), and so your unbracket import would assign that whole object to `DateTime`. The braces deconstruct that object, assigning `DateTime` value in the object to the `DateTime` variable in your code

Answer (score 5):

## Importing

I'd like to make an explanation with general **ES6** syntax.

Let’s import those amazing helpful helper functions:

```
import { sayName, sayAnimal } from './Helpers';
import whatsYourFlava from './Helpers';
sayName('Sam');
//Hello Sam
sayAnimal('Giraffe');
//What animal? Giraffe
whatsYourFlava('grapes');
//I'm liking grapes
```

**When importing named exports, you’ll have to wrap them in curly braces.** If you’re importing multiple exports from the same module, you can concatenate them, comma based, and use them in the same wrapping curly braces. This looks a lot like destructuring in **ES6**, but actually doesn’t have anything to do with it.

**When you import, and omit the curly braces**, it will look for the default export in the module you’re importing from. Because it knows it has to look for the default export, you can use any random name for your import. This will work too:

```
import bruhGetMoney from './Helpers';
bruhGetMoney('money');
//I'm liking money
```

I hope this would be a clearer thing for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In react I had a problem and was unable to import in the ways mentioned. But this way it worked:

```
import * as luxon from "luxon"
const { DateTime } = luxon
```

It should currently work in Vue as well.